# Overfull box with addmargin (KOMA-Script) and SideBySideExample (fvrb-ex)

Tags: koma-script

Why does the following code produce an overfull error and how can I avoid that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fvrb-ex}
\begin{document}
  \begin{addmargin}[4em]{0em}
    \begin{SideBySideExample}[xrightmargin=3cm]
      a
    \end{SideBySideExample}
  \end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that `fvrb-ex` uses `\textwidth` instead of `\linewidth` for setting the side-by-side objects; indeed, if I add `\textwidth=\linewidth` before \begin{SideBySideExample}` the overfull box message disappears. This could have adverse effects, though, if a page break is evaluated during the processing of an example.

Answer (score 1):

As **egreg** has correctly stated in his comment, the definition of SideBySideExample uses `\textwidth` and not `\linewidth` (see the line right after the first `\end{minipage}` in the original definition):

```
\newcommand{\SideBySide@Example}[1]{%
\@tempdimb=\FV@XRightMargin
\advance\@tempdimb -5mm
\begin{minipage}[c]{\@tempdimb}
\fvset{xrightmargin=0pt}
\catcode‘\^^a3=9\relax%
\NoHighlight@Attributes % To suppress possible highlighting
#1
\end{minipage}%
\@tempdimb=\textwidth
\advance\@tempdimb -\FV@XRightMargin
\advance\@tempdimb 5mm
\begin{minipage}[c]{\@tempdimb}
\VerbatimInput[gobble=0,commentchar=^^a3,commandchars=^^a7^^b5^^b6,numbersep=3pt,
xleftmargin=5mm,xrightmargin=0pt]{\jobname.tmp}
\end{minipage}}
```

One could change this to use `\linewidth` using, for example, a direct redefinition or, for brevity, the `etoolbox` package to patch the command:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fvrb-ex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SideBySide@Example}{\@tempdimb=\textwidth}{\@tempdimb=\linewidth}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{addmargin}[4em]{0em}
    \begin{SideBySideExample}[xrightmargin=6cm]
      a
    \end{SideBySideExample}
  \end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```